# Get the full path of the most recent sub directory inside a directory using batch

Tags: batch-file

I am new to batch scripting..

How do i get the most recent directory's complete path and output in the text file using batch script?

I tried some commands but not able to achive.

Comment: What does "most recent directory" mean? The one you've most recently visited? The one most recently created? The directory named "most recent"?

Comment: Yes I need the last modified directory's relative path.

Comment: You should include that information in your question, so we know what it is you're asking. :-) If it's not clear, it's more difficult to answer your question, and takes longer for you to get help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like this :

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b/ad/o-d') do (
echo %%~fa>output.txt
goto:eof
)
```

It will create output.txt with the complete path of the last directory created.

Comment: Thanks a lot. it works fine. However i want the path to be clickable so i need the relative path now. Something lie \\Folder1\Folder2.